# Akka IO Serial communication using java

Tags: io, serial-port, akka

I am very much new to Akka IO. I have a requirement of client server communication happening over serial port using Akka IO. I have read about JOdersky serial IO library. (https://github.com/jodersky/flow), but that didin't help much as it is very much specific to Scala. Does anyone have any idea on how to setup this JOdersky library for java based developments in Akka. It will be very useful if some related samples are posted.

Comment: The IO interface consists just of messages that you send to actors, which works from Java as well as from Scala, take a look at Terminal.scala where you can see the Serial.Open, Serial.Opened, etc. messages.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you can use flow from Java as well. Akka itself is written in Scala isn't it?

Another approach might be to use similar tech:

https://github.com/jodersky/ace/blob/master/scala/jssc/src/main/scala/com/github/jodersky/ace/jssc/Serial.scala

Same author has this hidden away in another project. Still scala, but it's using the java-simple-serial-connector library instead of flow so you could perhaps more easily adapt this to a java solution.

https://code.google.com/p/java-simple-serial-connector/

They way that AKKA IO appears to be working is by having specific actors bound to the IO duties which can send messages to actor refs that you provide. Using the event listener in jssc should make this pretty straight-forward.